# how to run two thread parallel in java

Tags: java, multithreading

i am trying to run two thread Parallel but according to the output they are not looks like parallel.i am new to java and unable to figure out my mistake.

here is my little effort.

**Main class code:**

```
public class FirstProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    TwoThread tt=new TwoThread();
    tt.start();

     for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
System.out.println("Main class Thread");}
}
```

**Second class code**

```
public class TwoThread extends Thread {
public void run() {//
    for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        System.out.println("New Thread");
                         }
                  } 
             }
```

**output**

```
Main class Thread
Main class Thread
Main class Thread
New Thread
New Thread
New Thread
```

**Expecting output**

```
Main class Thread
New Thread
Main class Thread
New Thread
Main class Thread
New Thread
```

Comment: Strongly, strongly, strongly recommend **not** putting `}` on the same line as the code in the block. Hard to read, hard to maintain...

Comment: There is no reason to expect that output. Just because threads run in parallel doesn't mean that they will negotiate taking turns writing something. Try writing thousands of lines instead. You'll see they run in parallel.

Comment: In your expected output, each thread alternatively stops while it waits for the other to access the shared resource. That's not running in parallel, that's running in alternation.

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting here. OP clearly researched how to create threads (didn't just call `run`, for instance) and didn't understnad the result he/she got, so showed full code (other than a missing `}`) and output and what he/she expected and asked why. Yes, the expectation was naive. We've all been naive at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're starting the second thread correctly¹, and your threads are (potentially) running in parallel. But that doesn't mean that they'll necessarily be scheduled to interleave like that. There's also a bit of thread startup time.

If you made your threads run for longer, you'd see that they are running in parallel.

For instance, on my mid-spec multi-core machine, running 20k loops rather than 3 in each thread showed blocks "Main class Thread" interspersed with blocks of "New Thread". The first block of "Main class Thread" was fairly large, which isn't a surprise because of the startup time for the new thread, and then the blocks of output from the two threads were largish but interwoven. YMMV, though, since thread scheduling can vary.

---

¹ Although in general, the recommendation is to `implement Runnable` rather than `extend Thread`, and then use `new Thread(new TwoRunnable())` to create it.

Comment: You could also add `sleep` calls in between the lines. That will show interleaving.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect any ordered output from a multithreaded application (until you artificially synchronising/joining your threads).

When you `start()` a `Thread` it submitted to the `Thread Scheduler`.

`Thread Scheduler` is a part of the JVM that decides which thread should run. There is no guarantee that which `Thread` will be chosen for execution. The `Thread Scheduler` mainly uses preemptive or time slicing scheduling to schedule the threads.

If you have multiple cores, both threads can run in parallel (and that's the difference between concurrent and parallel execution). But still it doesn't change the fact that it depends on `Thread Scheduler` and the execution is unpredictable.

Comment: On a multi-core machine, they can actually run at the same time, too.